Can not upload profile picture on Flutter project
I am trying to implement profile photo on my project but could not manage.
// Update User Data
  void updateUser(String newUsername, String newProfilePictureUrl,
      int newVideoCount, String newBio) {
    username = newUsername;
    profilePictureUrl = newProfilePictureUrl;
    videoCount = newVideoCount;
    bio = newBio;
    notifyListeners();
  }

Future<void> uploadProfilePicture(File image) async {
    try {
      // Get Current User
      User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

      if (user != null) {
        // Upload File to Firebase Storage

        Reference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('profile_pictures/${user.uid}.jpg');
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(image);

        TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
        String downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

It shows as updated when i first upload the picture. But when i go back to feed page, avatar is still the same.
What should i do?
Thank you.

When you go back reload page or related API.

@DroidFlutter thanks a lot for the feedback but what do you mean?

It shows picture is updated, and in your previous (feed) page you get old(same avatar) picture, so just try to reload page (feed page).
